# error in splitting a string using "re.findall"

Tags: python

i need to split a string into three values (x,y,z) the string is something like this (48,25,19)

i used **"re.findall"** and it works fine but sometimes it produces this error

**`(plane_X, plane_Y, plane_Z = re.findall("\d+.\d+", planepos)`**

**`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0))`**

this is the code:

```
    def read_data():
        # reading from file
        file = open("D:/Cs/Grad/Tests/airplane test/Reading/Positions/PlanePos.txt", "r")
        planepos = file.readline()
        file.close()
        file = open("D:/Cs/Grad/Tests/airplane test/Reading/Positions/AirportPosition.txt", "r")
        airportpos = file.readline()
        file.close()
        # ==================================================================
        # spliting and getting numbers
        plane_X, plane_Y, plane_Z = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", planepos)
        airport_X, airport_Y, airport_Z = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", airportpos)
        return plane_X,plane_Y,plane_Z,airport_X,airport_Y,airport_Z
```

what i need is to **split** the string **(48,25,19)** to **x=48,y=25,z=19**
so if someone know a better way to do this or how to solve this error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only works for numbers with a decimal point and not for integers, hence the error. You can instead strip the string of parentheses and white spaces, then split the string by commas, and map the resulting sequence of strings to the `float` constructor:

```
x, y, z = map(float, planepos.strip('() \n').split(','))
```

Comment: this makes more sense than what i wrote but still it produces some errors but i can live fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` which safely evaluates your string:

```
import ast

s = '(48,25,19)'
x, y, z = ast.literal_eval(s)

# x => 48
# y => 25
# z => 19
```

Comment: thank you for your help this will be helpful but the previous one will help me more as i need to convert it later thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are integers, you can use the regex:

```
re.findall(r"\d+","(48,25,19)")                                         
['48', '25', '19']
```

If there are mixed numbers:

```
re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?","(48.2,25,19.1)")                           
['48.2', '25', '19.1']
```

Comment: thank you your comment helped me to understand how it works.